# How to detect if child node has been touched: Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, skspritenode

I have an `SKSpriteNode`. This `SKSpriteNode` has several children. How can I detect if it has been touched? Now, let me be clear, I already know to set up a button in SpriteKit and I tried using the same code I used to detect if the main parent node has been touched, but it didn't work. The button doesn't do anything. Is there a way to fix this? Also, I already tried to set user interaction to true for the child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to track continuous touches (i.e.. directional arrows).

You need to keep track of the touches, in the SKScene node, or in the parent view controller:

```
var touches = Set<UITouch>()

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touches.formUnion(touches)
    self.updateTouches()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touches.formUnion(touches)
    self.updateTouches()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touches.subtract(touches)
    self.updateTouches()
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.touches.subtract(touches)
    self.updateTouches()
}
```

For each touch, translate the coordinates to relative to the SKNode. Check if any of the touches is within the accumulated frame of the SKNode. The accumulated frame is the total bounding area of the node and all of its descendants.

```
private func isTouching(node: SKNode) -> Bool {

    guard let parent = node.parent else {
        return false
    }

    let frame = node.calculateAccumulatedFrame()

    for touch in touches {

        let coordinate = touch.location(in: parent)

        if frame.contains(coordinate) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

For example:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    let touchingJump = isTouching(node: jumpButtonNode)

    if touchingJump {
        print("jump")
    }
}
```

Comment: @appzYourLife Are you referring to the fact that it does not compile with swift 2?

Comment: It doesn't compile with Swift 2.2. Which version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @appzYourLife It's Swift 3. The version wasn't specified by the asker. The general idea should be clear. The exact implementation depends on the use case. I can translate it to Swift 2 if it will help you.

Comment: If it's Swift 3 it's not a problem for me :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wasn't going to directly copy the code so the version doesn't really matter. Anyway, I really like the idea of detecting the coordinate and I think that's going to be the most useful in this situation. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: is checkTouching(node: jumpButtonNode) comes out of nowhere for me. Where/how/why does this work?

Comment: @Confused Fixed - thanks for the tip. It works by recursively descending the node hierarchy, until a node is found which encompasses any of the touches.

Comment: and why isTouching a private function? Private to what? Where?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Touched")
}
```

on class associated to every node you want to monitor for touch events. So you should add this method to every descendant of your main `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: @LukeVanIn: I added a print to my method. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement this method on class associated to every node you to monitor for touch events" So you should add this method to every descendant of your main SKSpriteNode? Where is that, in the code? I was under the impression touchesBegan only works in SKView... but I'm confused...